# invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I am getting below error when i am trying to set classpath. I am using CentyOS. I am trying to complie a java file in command prompt for that i am setting the classpath. On executing the same java program in Intellij , it runs fine. On executing the same from command prompt it shows error for missing jars so for that i added the classpath to that lib on which the error is seen.

```
[root@a admin]# export CLASSPATH=/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/org.json-20120521.jar ;/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/testng-6.8.21.jar 
invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. I am new in both java and linux, thanks!!

Answer (score 18):

In unix environment the delimiter for classpath is `:` so change it to:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/org.json-20120521.jar:/home/admin/TagAPI/lib/testng-6.8.21.jar
```

`;` is the command delimiter.

Comment: I had the same error starting java with multiple paths in the classpath (-cp) separated by semicolons. Thanks for the hint.