# Java is using home as root directory on Linux

Tags: java, linux, directory, bufferedreader

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and this behavior is displayed using both OpenJDK 7 and Oracle 7 & 8.

Traditionally, Java applications will treat the folder they are in as the default location. For example, on Windows, a java program in ".../Desktop/Foldername"  opening "file.txt" will locate ".../Desktop/Foldername/file.txt". This location changes based on where you put the executable .jar file.

On my linux installation however, opening "file.txt" will, regardless of the directory the application is located in, will open "/home/file.txt". Why is this, and how can I make it behave like in windows?

**Edit:**
This is using bufreader

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: Executing it by clicking on it, and running with either OpenJDK or Oracle

Comment: What you call the "default" location is not where the .jar file is placed, it is actually in which directory the process was started. I don't know what happens on your system when starting it from the UI, but if you open a terminal, navigate to the .jar file location and start the java process from there, then that will be the home of that process, thus looking for relative Paths starting there.

Comment: Tried doing that. I was able to do it before, but for whatever reason, now it gives me an error no matter what file i try: invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139321/invalid-file-bad-magic-number-exec-format-error

Comment: tried that. It says no such file or directory

Comment: ah wait, nevermind, that guy has a different situation. Not sure what he's trying to do as he has two different filepaths. I only know of my one

Comment: do you have a semicolon in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what my classpath is

Comment: eh, nevermind. I only have to have it work on this specific machine, so I'll just change it to an absolute filepath